# How to check if ssd/nvme/flashdrive/external-disks is fake

Tags: hard-disk

Since there's a lot of counterfeit disks lately (external disks that claim to be normal 500GB/1TB/2TB/4TB but inside it's only 16GB flashdisk and heavy iron, or nvme but it's just small microsd plugged inside and covered with heatsink so people wont get suspicious, flashdisk/microsd claiming to be 128GB but apparently it's only 4GB/8GB with firmware hack), what's the proper way to check whether the device I bought is real or not?

Comment: `man badblocks` either in `-n` or `-w` modes.

Comment: running with `sudo badblocks -svw -b 1048576 -t random /dev/sdxxx`, hopefully that can check whether this one counterfeit or not

Comment: How did it go? ...

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov looks ok :3 this one counterfeit, i just got suspected because they were try to sell me old athlon PC (with lots of dust)